# Authenticate users using only password

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, npm, cryptography

I need to make an authentication system for an express app I'm building. The client asked to have a password system that uses just a 4-digit pin. I have the code setup to save and hash the pin with the rest of the user info when creating a new user and the project is just an in-house server so it doesn't need to handle a ton of users.

My problem is signing the user back in. I'm using bycrypt to hash the password, but bycrypt generates a completely new hash for identical strings.

What I'm having trouble doing is fetching the user by doing a `WHERE hash=hash` SQL search. But that's not working because the hash is different every time even when the passwords are identical.

I could get all the users and iterate over all of them and use bycrypt's `.compare` method. But that won't work in the long run as the amount of users grows, and bycrypt is build to take a long time on cpu's to help prevent brute-force attacks.

I could also build my own hashing function. However, that would make it so I have to store a salt with each user to make each password unique. Then that brings up the same problem of not having the same hash for identical strings.

I know this is vague but I need some help thinking up a way to get the user by fetching it using the hashed password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just store the PIN as plain text. Using a hashing function on a 4 digit PIN does nothing but provide a false sense of security.  Even an intentionally slow hashing function is easy to brute force if there are only 10,000 possible inputs.

> What I'm having trouble doing is fetching the user by doing a `WHERE hash=hash` SQL search

Are you saying that you don't even know who the person claims to be, but are using the 4 digit pin as both the claim and the proof?  It sounds like you building a system with only a pretense of security.

Comment: Hm thats true, I didn't think of why hashing is used. I think I came up with a solution, I'll make the 4-digit passkeys only accessible when a key is used first. So the app will be logged in by an admin, then the people can use the 4-digit pins to sign in. Thanks for pointing that out!